# Central limit theorem with dice

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

We throw a fair coin until we have 50 heads. What is the approximate probability that we flip more than 120 times?

I guess I can rewrite it so as to ask what's the probability that in 120 flips I have less than 50 heads. So, we have iid random variables
$X_i =\begin{cases}1 \ \ \ \text{if heads} \\
0 \ \ \ \text{if tails}\end{cases}$

$\Bbb P(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{120}X_i-\Bbb nE[X_i]}{\sqrt{nVar(X_i)}}<\frac{50-\Bbb nE[X_i]}{\sqrt{nVar(X_i)}})=\Bbb P(Z<\frac{50-\Bbb 120\cdot 1/2}{\sqrt{120\cdot 1/4}})=\Bbb P(Z<-1.826)\approx0.0339.$

Am I correct?

Comment: Hint: flip a coin 120 times, what is the probability that you will see fewer than 50 heads? You seem to be over-complicating it. Also, it isn't clear where 2100 comes from.

Comment: That number appears to be too low.  It's not hard to do the straight binomial calculation, which yields $0.027389898$.  Or you can use the normal approximation, but if you do then you should be sure to use the continuity correction.  This yields $0.027617127$

Comment: Note that $\frac{50-\Bbb 2100\cdot 1/2}{\sqrt{2100\cdot 1/4}}$ evaluates to $-43.64$ rather than the $-2.18$ that you claim. The probability that a standard normal is below $-43.64$ is vanishingly small. Thus, the answer that you got is too small, but the answer that you should have obtained from your own expression would have been much, much smaller still.

Comment: @JohnColeman it's a typo. I've made changes.

Comment: As edited, it is roughly correct, but lacks the continuity correction (giving rise to an approximation which is not as good as it could be). You should use 49.5 rather than 50.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks. Continuity correction leads me to 0.0418.

Comment: It shouldn't lead there. @lulu above gave what it should lead to